# Saving search results rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a rather complex search on few of my models. I combine the results into one array which contains all of my models. I'm wondering what is the best way to get the permlink to my search.

I was thinking of creating another model named `SearchResult` which would have many to many relation to all my models in search described above.

So that way I can reference from single `SearchResult` all the models that are part of that search result? Is this a good approach to this? Should I do something else instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a tutorial for this exact scenario on RailsCasts.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised

Comment: Do you have any free resources that I can look at?

Comment: @London Railscasts is really worth the 10 dollar.